# ffmpeg: Combine a audio (.wav) and video in (.rgb) format

Tags: ffmpeg, multimedia

I want to synchronously play audio (.wav) file and video which is provided to me in rgb format.

The rgb file contains all the rgb images in the video frames. How can I combine rgb file and audio using ffmeg to get output video which can be played on vlc player?

Input 1 : audio.wav

Input 2 : allimages.rgb

Output : A video file which can be played in vlc player.

I was looking at ffmpeg documentation but couldn't find anything for rgb input. It would be great help if you can provide the ffmpeg command for doing above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got with this is using below command, but I see Green and Pink colors in my video after I play it. I think I am missing something in the ffmpeg command. **Can anyone tell me what is wrong in above command and help to improve video quality and remove green and pink colors?**

```
ffmpeg -s 480x270 -r 15 -pix_fmt gbrp  -i /Users/sandeep/Downloads/Videos/input.rgb -c:v libx264 -y output.mp4
```

[image]

Comment: You need to correctly identify the pixel format of the input. How was it generated?

Comment: I have been given input files as part of task and I don't know how it was generated. I think the rgb images in input have green and pink colors. Is there any way we can tell ffmeg to do: r = r & 0xff, g = g & 0xff, b = b & 0xff. I tried to read r,g,b values and then AND it with 0xff. and then display frame which has no green and pink colors.

Comment: You should try the following pixel formats: `rgb24` `bgr24` `0rgb` `rgb0` `0bgr` `bgr0` If none of these work, we may have to swap channels.